# Memory leak through IClipboardDataPasteEventImpl

Tags: memory-leaks, android

I noticed an odd memory increase in one of my Activities. Hence I ran a little test: I opened the dialog multiple times (open - close - open - close ....) and the memory kept increasing. So I used the DDMS to dump an HPROF file and opened it in [MAT](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) (Memory analyzer). The leak suspect report indicated, that the main reason for the growing memory consumption was this:

[image]

So I did a histogramm, to check that dialog I ran my tests on and what's keeping it alive. Turns out, it's kept alive by it's **AutoCompleteTextViews**, which in turn are kept alive by **android.widget.TextView$IClipboardDataPasteEventImpl.** However there are no immediate dominators for IClipboardDataPasteEventImpl (except of course the GC Root). I tried to find that IClipboardDataPasteEventImpl  on the internet and I searched grepcode (the android source), but the only thing I could come up with was this [blog entry](http://splash5.blogspot.de/2012/03/galaxy-s2-memory-leak-with-textview.html). I can't read whatever language that is, but what I could read are the English words thrown in, which indicates, that it might be a bug on the Samsung Galaxy SII (the phone I am using, running android 2.3.x), related to the ClipboardManager. However I am unsure of this (I want to fix this, hence I am disinclined to simply accept it to be an unfixable bug) and I have no clue, where this Clipboard is spawned and why. I would greatly appreciate any pointers/ideas on the matter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My memleak investigation also brought me here. Im having problems with Activity leaking over EditText. android.widget.TextView$IClipboardDataPasteEventImpl object is holding the EditText which is holding the activity. This happens on Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1, and Galaxy Tab 2 10.1, 7.0. I wasn't able to reproduce it on other non Samsung devices (Asus, Acer).

The bad thing is that I didn't find a solution for it yet :)

Comment: Hello and welcome to the club ;D ! Well I messed around it with a while and just like you, I wasn't able to reproduce this on other non-samsung devices. However: All those ClipboardDataPaste stuff does seem to get cleaned up eventually, it just takes a while. Can you confirm that? Or does that stuff actually lead to Out of Memory Exceptions in your case?

Comment: This ClipboardDataPaste is some Samsung invention because this class doesn't exist in oryginal Android sources. Good job Samsung :) You are right with returning the memory. After some time objects are garbage collected but Im able to run a few leaking activities during that time. Is it doing OOM? Not really now as I'm not so critical with memory but I suppose if I was closer to the heapSize it would cause OOM then.

Comment: We're pretty close to the heaps maximum, so far the only thing throwing OOMs was taking pictures on the Galaxy SIII (hover that's the only device we know of so far, Note, SII and others seem fine). Yeah lol I searched for that ClipboardDataPaste all over the internet - and found pretty much nothing :O so I figured it must be a Samsung invention... Sometimes I really wish they were less inventive -_-

Comment: I accepted this answer now, as I am afraid gathering intel is the next best hing to an answer/solution (which I am not even sure there is or that it's even necessary).

Comment: Add Galaxy S4 (Android 4.2.2) to the list of problematic devices. See post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18348049/android-edittext-memory-leak

Answer (score 8):

#### Investigation

Here're my research results:

- It happens to any `Activity` whose content view consists of an `EditText`. `finish()`ing the `Activity` does not get it garbage collected as it is being referenced, like this:

  ```
  activity com.example.MyActivity
  <- mContext android.widget.TextView
      <- this$0 android.widget.TextView$IClipboardDataPasteEventImpl
          <- this$1 android.widget.TextView$IClipboardDataPasteEventImpl$1
              <- referent java.lang.ref.FinalizerReference
  ```
- It happens on my *Samsung Galaxy Tab GT-P7300* running *Android 4.0.4*, but not on my *Samsung Galaxy Mini GT-S5570* running *Android 2.2.1*.
- The `IClipboardDataPasteEventImpl` objects eventually get freed, actually, but only at times which seems to be unpredictable.

Since they are referenced by `java.lang.ref.FinalizerReference`, I believe that the `IClipboardDataPasteEventImpl` objects are waiting to be `finalize()`'d, which happens only when the JVM feels like to. For details, check out these SO questions:

- [is memory leak? why java.lang.ref.Finalizer eat so much memory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8355064/1402846)
- [Very strange OutOfMemoryError](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10436140/1402846)

---

#### <strike>Solution /</strike> Workaround

Sorry, no solution, but here's my best workaround:

**In `onDestroy()` of your `Activity`, free as many references to other objects as possible** (especially the big ones, such as bitmaps, collections, and child views of your activity), like this:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy()
{
    // Free reference to large objects.
    m_SomeLargeObject = null;
    m_AnotherLargeObject = null;

    // For ArrayList, if you are a paranoid to null, you may call clear() and then trimToSize().
    m_SomeLargeArrayList.clear();
    m_SomeLargeArrayList.trimToSize();

    // Free child views.
    m_MyButton = null;

    // Free adapters.
    m_ListViewAdapter = null;

    ... etc.

    // Don't forget to chain the call to the superclass.
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

This way, we can at least reduce the casualties and hopefully won't go out of memory before the JVM has the mood to finialize and collect all those evil `IClipboardDataPasteEventImpl` objects.

In an ideal world of garbage collected environment, this would be unnecessary, but I guess we should all realize that our world is not perfect, and we just have to live with the flaws.

---

Below is my translation of the [original blog entry](http://splash5.blogspot.com/2012/03/galaxy-s2-memory-leak-with-textview.html) (in Chinese) as mentioned in the question. Hopefully this can give everybody a better understanding about the issue.

> #### Galaxy S2 memory leak with TextView
>
> 不知道是不是哪邊弄錯

Not sure where it went wrong

> 但是galaxy s2的textview會產生memory leak

But the `textview` of *galaxy s2* causes *memory leaks*

> leak是發生在android.widget.TextView$IClipboardDataPasteEventImpl這個interface上

*Leak* happens on the `interface` `android.widget.TextView$IClipboardDataPasteEventImpl`

> 它會抓住mContext造成整個activity沒辦法被gc

It holds the `mContext`, stopping the `activity` from being *gc*'ed

> 同樣的程式在htc sensation(2.3.4)跟se xperia arc(2.3.4)和acer liquid(2.1)都沒有問題

No such problem with the same app on *htc sensation(2.3.4)*, *se xperia arc(2.3.4)* and *acer liquid(2.1)*

> 而且網路上完全找不到android.widget.TextView$IClipboardDataPasteEventImpl相關的資料

And, I can't find anything related to `android.widget.TextView$IClipboardDataPasteEventImpl` on the web at all

> android source code裡也找不到 看起來應該是samsung自己加的東西...

Not even in the *android source code*, so it seems to be something added by *samsung* themselves...

> 之前的opengl viewport bug 已經夠頭痛了 接下來soundpool相關bug也搞累很多人

The *opengl viewport bug* was a headache already, and the *soundpool* related *bug* had frustrated many

> 現在這個memory leak又來攪局...

And now, here comes a *memory leak* messing around...

> 看來手機外型還是比較重要 /_\... 外型好先吸到人來買 bug再慢慢修就好

Seems that the appearance of mobile phones are more important /_\... good appearance attracts customers; *bugs* could be fixed later

> [後記]

[P.S.]

> 經過一些試驗發現 只要按HOME button回到桌面，那些leak就會被釋放掉...

After some tests, I found out that the *leaks* will be freed by pressing the *HOME button* to go back to the desktop...

> logcat會顯示一行Hide Clipboard dialog at Starting input: finished by someone else... !

It shows *Hide Clipboard dialog at Starting input: finished by someone else... !* in *logcat*

> 看起來galaxy s2裡面有偷偷對clipboard作一些操作...

It seems that *galaxy s2* is operating on the *clipboard* under the hood...

> 但如果一直保持在app裡面運作的話，那些leak還是會存在...最後應該會發生OOM exception

But if we stay in the *app*, those *leaks* remain... eventually an *OOM exception* would occur

> 現在只能期望galaxy s2 的ics版會修掉這個怪問題了...

Now we can only hope that this strange problem would be resolved in the *ics* version of *galaxy s2*...

Comment: Wow, thanks a bunch for the input :) ! And although there is probably no solution to this (as it only affects Samsung devices and apparently not even all of them?), this helps getting an understanding of the issue at hand. I'd say cleaning up one's resources in onDestroy is generally a good practice and even if it does not solve this problem, it'll most likely help avoiding other memory related issues. So once again: Thanks a lot for your input :) !

Comment: Do we have a solution by now?

Comment: @MobDev I am afraid not, the problem persists. When running a leak suspect report in eclipse using a heap dump from a Samsung Device such as the SIII or the Galaxy Note iclipboarddatapasteeventimpl is one of the prime suspects and all other suspects are often related to thise one (when back-tracking the dominator tree).