# Android FinalizerReference using 7mb of RAM

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I know that there are 2-3 topic about this, there were problems with `FinalizerReference`, but it's still not explained well. I have a question about this class and how do things in it work.

No matter what I do in my app, `FinalizerReference` always keep 5-10 `RAM` for itself, and my question is:

**is this a normal behavior that I don't have to worry about?**

As I know, Java objects are freed, but 'pointers' stay in the memory and they're cleaned with the next GC (aswell as normal objects cleaned with GC, with no reference to it).

For me, this is a little bit wrong, because if I have ~64 MB's of RAM to use with my application and 10mb are wasted - there must be an issue.

I checked it all, removed all the leaks I had and currently my app just stays at 18~mb RAM (7 RAM - graphics, 2 RAM - Objects). The rest - `FinalizerReference` ;/

Here's a screenshot from the AppHeap:
[image]

here's a screen from it's instances:

[image]

and here's my memory monitor (it stays in this form for 30 minutes):

[image]

Also, in the 'Instances' panel, there are 50 entries including ~5 from my code and libraries I use. The rest is from Android - InputManagers, Parcels, Proxies etc.

**Edit**

This happens on Galaxy S5.
On Android Emulator I get ~2MB from FinalizerReference

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I didn't solve the problem, but got an advice that I should check on an empty project.

Tried with:

- Android Studio Windows x32
- Android Studio Windows x64
- IntelliJIDEA x32
- IntelliJIDEA x64

All of these cause the `FinalizerReference` to keep `5-10 mb` of `RAM` for itself, on empty and non-empty projects.

Just ignore the issue and keep writing code.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with `FinalizerReference`, only on Nexus 5.

Here is screenshot of heap dump from Android Studio.
[image]

After some research, I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666382/possible-memory-leak-through-finalizerreference#comment70708355_33666382) comment, where it said that this could be caused by System.

Also, I have used Eclipse's **Memory Analysis Tool (MAT)**, which proved that so many `FinalizerReference` objects belong to System.

And, it didn't occupy so much memory as Android Studio's heap dump showed.

[image]

Comment: I mean system, because it has "System Class" written next to it and as much as I know, it means that android system has loaded that class

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem, and I created [a separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57027001/why-is-the-retained-heap-size-of-the-finalizerreference-class-so-large-in-the-m) and answer before finding yours. I think I actually got to the root of it.

tldr: Treating FinalizerReference like any other class when profiling, leads to repeated counting of the same memory when calculating Retained Size. So currently you can (almost always) regard the Retained Size of the FinalizerReference class reported by Memory Profiler as meaningless.

The "referent" field in a FinalizerReference instance should actually be more important than its two references ("prev" and "next") to other instances of FinalizerReference. Only the Shallow Size of the class should really contribute to the Retained Size of the app heap, along with any *other* objects that are merely waiting to be finalize()'d before being garbage collected.

I view this as a bug in Android Studio's Memory Profiler, and have filed [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/137499178).