# After app startup, 70% of the memory is occupied by FinalizerReference

Tags: android

I was investigating the memory consumption of my android app. Immediately after app startup, I clicked 'Dump Java Heap' and the first class on the list is FinalizerReference (java.lang.ref). It has over 800 instances and consume more than 70% of the total memory comsumption.

I understand it is for garbage collection. Unlikely it is because of memory leak since it was captured right after app startup without switching to another view. I did not do any heavy processing during startup, apart from reading something from the shared preference.

[Possible Memory leak through FinalizerReference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666382/possible-memory-leak-through-finalizerreference)

From this post, I tried to look on the referent field of the FinalizerReference, but it appears to be something that beyond my understanding e.g. Matrix, Canvas, Render Node. It sounds like UI components for me.

Here is my question:

1. Is there any way/tool for me to further debug the root cause of memory comsumption.
2. Is this something that I need to worry, or it is just the normal behavior of android memory management.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. A better tool would be useful, but only because it should show that the reported Retained Size of ~33 MB for FinalizerReference is not real memory consumption, just massive multiple counting of the same small amount of memory by the Memory Profiler. The Shallow Size of ~28 kB is important, but negligible. The way I investigated this (using Memory Profiler) is detailed in my answer to [my own similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57027001/why-is-the-retained-heap-size-of-the-finalizerreference-class-so-large-in-the-m).
2. You should not worry about FinalizerReference, at least not based on what you show here. You may need to worry about Memory Profiler, due to the meaningless Retained Size it reports for this class. I regard its calculation as a bug, and I filed [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/137499178).