# Java CMS garbage collection min heap

Tags: java, garbage-collection

In few of my services when checking the heap dump I am seeing `java.lang.ref.finalizer` taking up almost all space. There are thousands of instances of finalizer class in histogram.
(I don't use finalize() method in code or 3rd party libraries)

**My GC flags :** `-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -Xms7168m -Xmx7168m -XX:NewRatio=3`

While understanding the garbage collection mechanism I am having few queries.

**Statement 1 :**  If we set both the initial and maximum values of the heap as equal, the GC becomes slightly more efficient, because it never needs to figure out whether the heap should be resized.

**Statement 2 :** The JVM starts a concurrent cycle based on the occupancy of the heap. When it is
sufficiently full, the JVM starts background threads that cycle through the heap and
remove objects

If we go with `Statement2` first, then it would mean that in my case where minHeap = maxHeap, the JVM won't start garbage collection for a long time, as the initial heap size itself is larger.

***Question :*** Won't this make GC more inefficient contradicting `Statement1`, and in turn also cause memory error which I am facing (mentioned in the beginning), where too many objects are left in the heap to be GC collected for a long time and in turn filling up memory, to an extent where a Full GC is not happening?

Comment: It is entirely irrelevant, how many unused objects the heap memory contains. All that matters, is how much free memory is available to new allocations. Having an excessive amount of finalizers is an entirely different issue and definitely connected to your application, even if you’re not using `finalize()` on your own. Your definitely using lots of objects of a class which has a `finalize()`.

Comment: AFAIK AdaptiveSizePolicy was never enabled for CMS.

Comment: Also, re statement 2, the concurrent cycle is also time scheduled based on predictions of heap churn.

Comment: @Erik you mean in my case it is not enabled or in CMS generally doesn't support?

Comment: CMS doesn't support it. Again AFAIK, the implementation was never done fully and not enabled.

Comment: I have to add that I don't quite get what your question actually is. Do you get OOME? I mean, if the app works with acceptable response times, where is the problem?

Comment: @Erik The issue which I am facing is that my memory usage increases to the extent it reaches 99% at which time I restart the service to avoid OOM error.

And when I am taking the heap dump, its the `finalizer` object which is taking the space. Which I mentioned I am not using in code directly.
So, thinking if its because of setting equal min and max heap size, as GC pauses more in that case as larger space empty

Comment: @Erik this blog says that ApativeSizePolicy is there in CMS https://www.javacodebook.com/2013/08/13/garbage-collection-adaptive-size-policy-java-performance-tuning/

Comment: @arqam If you read it carefully it actually does not. But anyway, the definite word: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8034246

Comment: @arqam so what does your gc log say? And, you don't actually know that you'll get an OOME if you restart the app.

Comment: @arqam it might very well be that they think it works but in reality it doesn't.

Comment: @Erik when I restart the service, the available memory gets freed up and OOM error is not thrown, or maybe I have to check the logs for OOM.

Comment: @arqam of course the memory is freed, what else could happen? And of course you don't get an OOME. I'm trying to get to, what does the gc log say and do you actually get an OOME. And do you have a bad response time, bad performance or what?

Comment: @Erik we sort of get the alert when memory usage is high, and support at that time restarts the service to prevent the app from crashing.

Comment: @Erik also if CMS doesn't allow resizing of younger generation, so when we provide -xms and -xmx flags, then how does the JVM grow the heap from min to max as the `NewRatio=3` condition needs to be maintained between younger and older generation.

Comment: @arqam If you don't believe the openjdk bugs site, I don't know what to tell you. Anyway, I would advise you to set up gc logging to find out what's going on. Secondly, you have the switch -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=<some percentage> that tells CMS when to start a concurrent cycle and try to use that.

Comment: @Erik I actually want to understand how does -xms and -xmx play a role in CMS, because these flags would not make sense in case of CMS when we don't do resizing.

Comment: @arqam There is lot of information about that. ms sets the minimum size of the heap. If the app needs more heap it will take more from the os until it reaches mx. The adaptive policy is about the relationship between young and old gen.

Comment: @Erik in that case can we say that if xms=xmx, the GC pause will be higher and it can affect cleaning up of the finalizer objects, as the objects are inserted in the finalizer queue only after a GC is done.